# Google Form App Script Automatic URL Redirect

Tags: redirect, google-apps-script, google-forms

My problem is that I have Link on all my business cards that leads to a Google form. I no longer am using that form and have moved on to Sharepoint. I need to redirect users to the new site. I already have a link that users can click on to take them there, but I would rather have them automatically redirected.

Is it possible to automatically redirect a user to another page from a Google Form using Google App Script?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that directly in Apps script.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to do this with apps script. Close the form and place the new url there which i assume that's what you already did. Apps script cannot run inside a form as of april 2015, and even if it could, apps script cannot redirect automatically. At most you would be able to show an anchor.